# AePub Reader Error in Xcode 4.6

Tags: ios6, epub, xcode4.6, libxml2

I downloaded an open source epub reader called AePubReader its working fine.But When i tried to integrate with my application in xcode 4.6 it shows lots of errors due to the ARC .So i selected those files and set "-fno-objc-arc" flag .But after that  it shows error like `#include <libxml/tree.h> not found![this is the error i got ][1]`
$(SDK_DIR)"/usr/include/libxml2   i added this line then that problem is solved but   after that it shows "43 Errors"  something like "  Apple Mach-O Linker Error"most of them related to xml files

My error message

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_htmlParseDoc", referenced from:
      -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLString:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o

"_htmlReadMemory", referenced from:
      -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLData:encoding:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o
  "_xmlAddChild", referenced from:
      -[CXMLDocument(CXMLDocument_CreationExtensions) addChild:] in CXMLDocument_CreationExtensions.o
      -[CXMLElement(CXMLElement_CreationExtensions) addChild:] in CXMLElement_CreationExtensions.o
      -[CXMLElement(CXMLElement_CreationExtensions) setStringValue:] in CXMLElement_CreationExtensions.o
  "_xmlAddPrevSibling", referenced from:
      -[CXMLDocument(CXMLDocument_CreationExtensions) insertChild:atIndex:] in CXMLDocument_CreationExtensions.o
  "_xmlCopyNode", referenced from:
      -[CXMLNode copyWithZone:] in CXMLNode.o

```
"_xmlDocDumpFormatMemory", referenced from:
  -[CXMLDocument description] in CXMLDocument.o
```

"_xmlDocDumpMemory", referenced from:
      -[CXMLDocument XMLDataWithOptions:] in CXMLDocument.o
  "_xmlDocGetRootElement", referenced from:
      -[CXMLDocument initWithData:encoding:options:error:] in CXMLDocument.o
      -[CXMLDocument rootElement] in CXMLDocument.o
  "_xmlDocSetRootElement", referenced from:
      +[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_CreationExtensions) documentWithRootElement:] in CXMLNode_CreationExtensions.o
      -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLString:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o
  "_xmlFree", referenced from:
      -[CXMLDocument XMLDataWithOptions:] in CXMLDocument.o
      -[CXMLDocument description] in CXMLDocument.o
  "_xmlFreeDoc", referenced from:
      -[CXMLDocument dealloc] in CXMLDocument.o
  "_xmlFreeNode", referenced from:
      -[CXMLNode dealloc] in CXMLNode.o
  "_xmlGetCharEncodingName", referenced from:
      -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLString:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o
  "_xmlGetLastError", referenced from:
      -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLString:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o
      -[CXMLDocument initWithXMLString:options:error:] in CXMLDocument.o
      -[CXMLDocument initWithData:encoding:options:error:] in CXMLDocument.o

```
"_xmlNewDoc", referenced from:
  +[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_CreationExtensions) document] in CXMLNode_CreationExtensions.o
  +[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_CreationExtensions) documentWithRootElement:] in CXMLNode_CreationExtensions.o
```

"_xmlNewNode", referenced from:
      +[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_CreationExtensions) elementWithName:] in CXMLNode_CreationExtensions.o
      +[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_CreationExtensions) elementWithName:URI:] in CXMLNode_CreationExtensions.o
      +[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_CreationExtensions) elementWithName:stringValue:] in CXMLNode_CreationExtensions.o
  "_xmlNewNs", referenced from:
      +[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_CreationExtensions) elementWithName:URI:] in CXMLNode_CreationExtensions.o
  "_xmlNewPI", referenced from:
      +[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_CreationExtensions) processingInstructionWithName:stringValue:] in CXMLNode_CreationExtensions.o
  "_xmlNewText", referenced from:
      -[CXMLElement(CXMLElement_CreationExtensions) setStringValue:] in CXMLElement_CreationExtensions.o
  "_xmlNodeDumpOutput", referenced from:
      -[CXMLNode XMLStringWithOptions:] in CXMLNode.o
  "_xmlNodeSetContent", referenced from:
      -[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_CreationExtensions) setStringValue:] in CXMLNode_CreationExtensions.o
  "_xmlOutputBufferClose", referenced from:
      -[CXMLNode XMLStringWithOptions:] in CXMLNode.o
  "_xmlOutputBufferCreateIO", referenced from:
      -[CXMLNode XMLStringWithOptions:] in CXMLNode.o
  "_xmlOutputBufferFlush", referenced from:
      -[CXMLNode XMLStringWithOptions:] in CXMLNode.o
  "_xmlParseDoc", referenced from:
      -[CXMLDocument initWithXMLString:options:error:] in CXMLDocument.o
  "_xmlReadMemory", referenced from:
      -[CXMLDocument initWithData:encoding:options:error:] in CXMLDocument.o
  "_xmlResetLastError", referenced from:
      -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLString:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o
      -[CXMLDocument initWithXMLString:options:error:] in CXMLDocument.o
      -[CXMLDocument initWithData:encoding:options:error:] in CXMLDocument.o
  "_xmlSetNs", referenced from:
      -[CXMLElement(CXMLElement_CreationExtensions) addNamespace:] in CXMLElement_CreationExtensions.o
  "_xmlStrcmp", referenced from:
      -[CXMLElement elementsForName:] in CXMLElement.o
      -[CXMLElement elementsForLocalName:URI:] in CXMLElement.o
      -[CXMLElement attributeForName:] in CXMLElement.o
      -[CXMLElement attributeForLocalName:URI:] in CXMLElement.o
      -[CXMLElement namespaceForPrefix:] in CXMLElement.o
      -[CXMLElement resolvePrefixForNamespaceURI:] in CXMLElement.o
  "_xmlXPathEvalExpression", referenced from:
      -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLString:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o
      -[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_NamespaceExtensions) nodesForXPath:namespaceMappings:error:] in CXMLNode_XPathExtensions.o
      -[CXMLNode nodesForXPath:error:] in CXMLNode.o
  "_xmlXPathFreeContext", referenced from:
      -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLString:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o
      -[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_NamespaceExtensions) nodesForXPath:namespaceMappings:error:] in CXMLNode_XPathExtensions.o
      -[CXMLNode nodesForXPath:error:] in CXMLNode.o
  "_xmlXPathFreeObject", referenced from:
      -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLString:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o
      -[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_NamespaceExtensions) nodesForXPath:namespaceMappings:error:] in CXMLNode_XPathExtensions.o
      -[CXMLNode nodesForXPath:error:] in CXMLNode.o
  "_xmlXPathNewContext", referenced from:
      -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLString:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o
      -[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_NamespaceExtensions) nodesForXPath:namespaceMappings:error:] in CXMLNode_XPathExtensions.o
      -[CXMLNode nodesForXPath:error:] in CXMLNode.o
  "_xmlXPathRegisterNs", referenced from:
      -[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_NamespaceExtensions) nodesForXPath:namespaceMappings:error:] in CXMLNode_XPathExtensions.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

"_htmlParseDoc", referenced from:

```
  -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLString:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o
```

"_htmlReadMemory", referenced from:

```
  -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLData:encoding:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o
```

"_xmlAddChild", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLDocument(CXMLDocument_CreationExtensions) addChild:] in CXMLDocument_CreationExtensions.o


  -[CXMLElement(CXMLElement_CreationExtensions) addChild:] in CXMLElement_CreationExtensions.o


  -[CXMLElement(CXMLElement_CreationExtensions) setStringValue:] in CXMLElement_CreationExtensions.o
```

"_xmlAddPrevSibling", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLDocument(CXMLDocument_CreationExtensions) insertChild:atIndex:] in CXMLDocument_CreationExtensions.o
```

"_xmlCopyNode", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLNode copyWithZone:] in CXMLNode.o
```

"_xmlDocDumpFormatMemory", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLDocument description] in CXMLDocument.o
```

"_xmlDocDumpMemory", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLDocument XMLDataWithOptions:] in CXMLDocument.o
```

"_xmlDocGetRootElement", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLDocument initWithData:encoding:options:error:] in CXMLDocument.o


  -[CXMLDocument rootElement] in CXMLDocument.o
```

"_xmlDocSetRootElement", referenced from:

```
  +[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_CreationExtensions) documentWithRootElement:] in CXMLNode_CreationExtensions.o


  -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLString:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o
```

"_xmlFree", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLDocument XMLDataWithOptions:] in CXMLDocument.o


  -[CXMLDocument description] in CXMLDocument.o
```

"_xmlFreeDoc", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLDocument dealloc] in CXMLDocument.o
```

"_xmlFreeNode", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLNode dealloc] in CXMLNode.o
```

"_xmlGetCharEncodingName", referenced from:

```
  -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLString:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o
```

"_xmlGetLastError", referenced from:

```
  -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLString:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o


  -[CXMLDocument initWithXMLString:options:error:] in CXMLDocument.o


  -[CXMLDocument initWithData:encoding:options:error:] in CXMLDocument.o
```

"_xmlNewDoc", referenced from:

```
  +[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_CreationExtensions) document] in CXMLNode_CreationExtensions.o


  +[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_CreationExtensions) documentWithRootElement:] in CXMLNode_CreationExtensions.o
```

"_xmlNewNode", referenced from:

```
  +[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_CreationExtensions) elementWithName:] in CXMLNode_CreationExtensions.o


  +[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_CreationExtensions) elementWithName:URI:] in CXMLNode_CreationExtensions.o


  +[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_CreationExtensions) elementWithName:stringValue:] in CXMLNode_CreationExtensions.o
```

"_xmlNewNs", referenced from:

```
  +[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_CreationExtensions) elementWithName:URI:] in CXMLNode_CreationExtensions.o
```

"_xmlNewPI", referenced from:

```
  +[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_CreationExtensions) processingInstructionWithName:stringValue:] in CXMLNode_CreationExtensions.o
```

"_xmlNewText", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLElement(CXMLElement_CreationExtensions) setStringValue:] in CXMLElement_CreationExtensions.o
```

"_xmlNodeDumpOutput", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLNode XMLStringWithOptions:] in CXMLNode.o
```

"_xmlNodeSetContent", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_CreationExtensions) setStringValue:] in CXMLNode_CreationExtensions.o
```

"_xmlOutputBufferClose", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLNode XMLStringWithOptions:] in CXMLNode.o
```

"_xmlOutputBufferCreateIO", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLNode XMLStringWithOptions:] in CXMLNode.o
```

"_xmlOutputBufferFlush", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLNode XMLStringWithOptions:] in CXMLNode.o
```

"_xmlParseDoc", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLDocument initWithXMLString:options:error:] in CXMLDocument.o
```

"_xmlReadMemory", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLDocument initWithData:encoding:options:error:] in CXMLDocument.o
```

"_xmlResetLastError", referenced from:

```
  -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLString:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o


  -[CXMLDocument initWithXMLString:options:error:] in CXMLDocument.o


  -[CXMLDocument initWithData:encoding:options:error:] in CXMLDocument.o
```

"_xmlSetNs", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLElement(CXMLElement_CreationExtensions) addNamespace:] in CXMLElement_CreationExtensions.o
```

"_xmlStrcmp", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLElement elementsForName:] in CXMLElement.o


  -[CXMLElement elementsForLocalName:URI:] in CXMLElement.o


  -[CXMLElement attributeForName:] in CXMLElement.o


  -[CXMLElement attributeForLocalName:URI:] in CXMLElement.o


  -[CXMLElement namespaceForPrefix:] in CXMLElement.o


  -[CXMLElement resolvePrefixForNamespaceURI:] in CXMLElement.o
```

"_xmlXPathEvalExpression", referenced from:

```
  -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLString:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o


  -[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_NamespaceExtensions) nodesForXPath:namespaceMappings:error:] in CXMLNode_XPathExtensions.o


  -[CXMLNode nodesForXPath:error:] in CXMLNode.o
```

"_xmlXPathFreeContext", referenced from:

```
  -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLString:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o


  -[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_NamespaceExtensions) nodesForXPath:namespaceMappings:error:] in CXMLNode_XPathExtensions.o


  -[CXMLNode nodesForXPath:error:] in CXMLNode.o
```

"_xmlXPathFreeObject", referenced from:

```
  -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLString:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o


  -[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_NamespaceExtensions) nodesForXPath:namespaceMappings:error:] in CXMLNode_XPathExtensions.o


  -[CXMLNode nodesForXPath:error:] in CXMLNode.o
```

"_xmlXPathNewContext", referenced from:

```
  -[CXHTMLDocument initWithXHTMLString:options:error:] in CXHTMLDocument.o


  -[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_NamespaceExtensions) nodesForXPath:namespaceMappings:error:] in CXMLNode_XPathExtensions.o


  -[CXMLNode nodesForXPath:error:] in CXMLNode.o
```

"_xmlXPathRegisterNs", referenced from:

```
  -[CXMLNode(CXMLNode_NamespaceExtensions) nodesForXPath:namespaceMappings:error:] in CXMLNode_XPathExtensions.o
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: check this image url  https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_Uxl6SKFfzQ/UUwbGcJwyBI/AAAAAAAAAL0/z_d-CwH_3IE/s988/Screen+Shot+2013-03-22+at+2.13.30+PM.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add "libz.dylib" and "libxml2.dylib" to the "Link Binary With Libraries" items in the "Build Phases" of the target.

Comment: ok..I added  Now its showing 35 error ,before that it was 43 errors

Comment: You have to show the error messages, I cannot guess. Perhaps you have to add "libxml2.dylib" ?

Comment: ok i will comment the url address check this     https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-GbL2Bg58MgY/UUwe7BtLc3I/AAAAAAAAAMQ/PvxnmGih58Y/s988/Screen+Shot+2013-03-22+at+2.13.30+PM.png

Comment: Please add the error messages as text to your question. Did you try to add "libxml2.dylib" ?

Comment: Have you added "libxml2.dylib" ??